# Php preg_match_all matches only last element

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've this regex

```
{{([ a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\s*(?:\[([ a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\]\s*)*}}
```

and i need to match strings such as:

```
{{word with spaces}}
{{word with spaces [sub1]}}
{{word with spaces   [sub1]  [sub 2]  [Sub-3] }}
```

capturing `word with spaces`, and `sub1`, `sub 2`, `Sub-3`.

The regex is working but the for the sub-s string matching gives only the last match, i.e. `Sub-3`.
How to get all `sub1`, `sub 2`, `Sub-3`?
Thanks

Comment: Did you miss `}` in second line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another variant using `\G` that is bit faster and avoids empty matches:

```
(?:{{([\w-]+(?:\h+[\w-]+)*)|(?!\A)\G)(?:\h*\[([^]]+)]|\h*}})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRAerI/1)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

Answer (score 2):

To get the value for sub in mulitple times group 2 you might use `\G` to assert the position at the end of the previous match:

```
(?:{{([\w-]+(?: [\w-]+)*)|\G(?!$))(?:\h+\[([^]]+)\])?(?=.*})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IRaDQ6/1)

Comment: thanks, i knew \G, but somewhat difficult to use ;) the regex works, though it is returning many empty matches: is there a way to avoid these?

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ Yes you can, anubhava posted a version with an alternation to match either `\h*\[([^]]+)]` or `\h*}}` which will take take of that part.